# How to add a listview inside a row?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-row

I have a layout that looks like this
[image]

Now, I want the scores on the right side to be of dynamic size such that the score list is scrollable, but I tried a few ways, none of which could achieve what I wanted.

This was my initial attempt to do it

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        TeamTitleHorizontal(teamName: teamName, teamLogoUrl: teamLogoUrl),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.separated(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                return Container(
                  decoration: isWinners[i] ? textUnderlineDecoration : null,
                  child: Text(
                    scores[i],
                    style: scoreStyle,
                  ),
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                return spaceX(extra: 18.0);
              },
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: scores.length),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

On top of this I tried wrapping the parents and grand parents with `SizedBox` and giving them some hard coded width but still the entire widget was not visible.

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide height on horizontal ListView.

```dart
Expanded(
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 40,//your value
    child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
```

Comment: Thanks this cured my stress worth of 2 sleepless nights. 

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [/ui/layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout)